# Can I convert an IQueryable<T> to DbSet<T> with same generic type in .NET Core EF?

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core

```
// Foo.cs
new Bar().Convert(
  Enumerable.Empty<Client>().AsQueryable();
)


// Bar.cs
public Client[] Convert(IQueryable<Client> query)
{
    Client[] result;

    using (var ctx = new StockContext())
    {
        result = ctx.Clients.Concat(query).ToArray();
    }

    return result;
}
```

Please consider above codes, as `Foo.cs` and `Bar.cs` are not located in the same assembly so I want to pass an `IQueryable` to `Bar.cs` and convert it to `DbSet`.

If I run the codes exactly like what I wrote in above, it throws me `System.InvalidCastException: 'Unable to cast object of type  System.Linq.EnumerableQuery'1[Stock.Models.DTO.Client]' to type  Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbSet'1[Stock.Models.DTO.Client]'.'`

Comment: Why do you want to convert it to `DbSet`?

Comment: @GuruStron As `Bar.cs` is in DAL and `Foo.cs` is in Service Layer (SL), I cannot build `IQueryable` of `DbSet` in SL (no reference to EF in SL) so that I need to pass an `IQueryable` to DAL in order to let DAL convert `IQueryable` to `DbSet` and eventually can turn `DbSet` into "real" SQL

Comment: Can you show "real" SQL, cause in general case you can't convert `IQueryable` to `DbSet`.

Comment: @GuruStron "real" SQL means EF will convert `DbSet` into SQL for me under the hood. What I want to achieve is that I don't want to make any reference to EF from Service Layer so that I want to pass an `IQueryable` to DAL and let it do the DAL stuff for me. Is there any way to achieve it?

Comment: Please add concrete use-case. In general - no, you can't attach collection of complex types to your query in EF.

Comment: I dont really understand what you wanna achieve. But may be you can inject IQueryable<YourClass> (which waill assigned from DbSet<YourClass> type property of EF) to do all work with it? Usually I`m hide Identity DbContext behind interface. Because EF himself work well with .NET Standard and its fine to use it in business logic (Identity Context require .NET Core).